Ubuntu 22.04 - Time zone does not update automatically
The Problem
I'm doing some extended travel, and I notice that when I change locations, the time zone does not update automatically. My current work around is to just run sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata each time I switch locations. However, it'd be nice to not have to do this manually.
I'm looking for a solution that:

Makes the time zone update without human intervention (e.g., I don't have to run sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata in order for the time zone to update)
Does not require me to install a third-party script (I believe automatic time zone updates is a built-in feature that should work out of the box without third-party help; please correct me if I'm wrong on this).

Research I've Done
Below are the relevant posts I've read that haven't helped.

timezone not updated automatically: I updated /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf as suggested, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Auto Timezone doesn't update: my location services are enabled (see system info below) and I would prefer not to install a third-party script.
How can I make Ubuntu automatically detect the correct timezone based on my internet connection?: I would prefer not to install a third-party script
Automatically set Linux timezone according to location: I would prefer not to install a third-party script.
Would like local time to be automatically updated: The discussion in the comments doesn't have any suggestions.
Ubuntu 22.04 Auto Timezone is wrong: This question is unanswered.
Ubuntu 22.04.4 changing time zones stopped working: This question is unanswered.

My System Info

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS only (no dual boot), 64-bit on a Dell XPS 13 (9380).

Running gsettings get org.gnome.system.location enabled returns true (location services enabled; verified in the GUI as well)

Running gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.datetime automatic-timezone return true (automatic timezone enabled; verified in the GUI as well)

Output of timedatectl status


               Local time: Mon 2024-05-27 01:33:36 NZST
           Universal time: Sun 2024-05-26 13:33:36 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2024-05-26 13:33:36
                Time zone: Pacific/Auckland (NZST, +1200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no


Output of systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service

 systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-05-27 01:19:15 NZST; 1h 4min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 935 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Initial synchronization to time server 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18597)
     Memory: 1.6M
        CPU: 208ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─935 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd


Contents of /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
I've tried both of the following and neither worked.

[Time]
NTP=
FallbackNTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
RootDistanceMaxSec=5
PollIntervalMinSec=32
PollIntervalMaxSec=2048

and
[Time]
NTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
FallbackNTP=pool.ntp.org
RootDistanceMaxSec=5
PollIntervalMinSec=32
PollIntervalMaxSec=2048


Full output of systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/timesyncd.conf (including comments).

# /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the timesyncd.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# See timesyncd.conf(5) for details.

[Time]
NTP=
FallbackNTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
RootDistanceMaxSec=5
PollIntervalMinSec=32
PollIntervalMaxSec=2048

or
# /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the timesyncd.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# See timesyncd.conf(5) for details.

[Time]
NTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
FallbackNTP=pool.ntp.org
RootDistanceMaxSec=5
PollIntervalMinSec=32
PollIntervalMaxSec=2048


Is the OS running all the time and you do not reboot and login?

The configurations you said you tried and didn't work are both entirely commented out. You should try and uncomment either in their entirety and try again (I'd say use the first one). To test if it works just try and change your timezone to somehwere you're not currently in with sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata and reboot.

If it doesn't avail, please post the output of systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/timesyncd.conf

Thank you for the reply, @David. The OS isn't continuously running. I reboot every 1 - 2 weeks usually (but since I've been troubleshooting this, I've been rebooting every day / multiple times a day).

Thank you for the reply, @kos. And thank you for calling out the commented out lines . I did as you suggested, and set the time zone to Los Angeles using the dpkg-reconfigure command, uncommented out the lines of the config file, and rebooted. Neither version of the config updated my time zone to New Zealand after a reboot. I've updated my question to show the lines uncommented and the full output from the systemd-analyze command.

On a second thought; why should timesyncd even set the timezone? And even if if it should, from where would it fetch information about current location? To my understanding tymesyncd is just supposed to replace the behavior of an NTP daemon. Obviously there are ways to infer the current location even just from the current IP, I'm not saying it isn't possible at all, but simply the task feels out of scope for timesyncd. I did some research (which I should have done before commenting), it appears as though in fact tymesyncd has no such capability.

Every other forum / Q/A on SE suggests using a third party tool, and I'd wager that's because unfortunately there's just no native way (i.e. a service or a systemd facility) to accomplish this. Hopefully someone will prove me wrong, but unfortunately it feels like this is the case.

Thanks for the info on timesyncd capabilities, @kos. I assumed that since there is an "Automatic Time Zone" toggle in settings that this was something built in to the OS. But I've spent multiple weeks troubleshooting with no luck, so I'm inclined to agree with you that this is a feature that requires a third-party tool. I hope someone proves us wrong on this, as it really does seem like all the pieces are there (e.g., location services, NTP) for this to work out of the box.

You're right, it appears as though GNOME should be able to do this somehow (I have no idea how / where it would fetch the location information from). But regardless perhaps this would be worth a bug report? shrug

Thanks for the suggestion. I opened an issue here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gsettings-desktop-schemas/-/issues/58. We'll see if it gets any attention.
